# Can we do activations before convolution and maxpooling

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNNs and I have this questions in mind.

usually, in CNNs, we do convolution followed by activation (Relu) followed by maxpooling.

What if I want to use Activations first followed by convolution followed by maxpooling. How would that effect the network performance or is this method useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $f$ is monotonic increasing, $f(\text{maxpool}(x))$ is the same as $\text{maxpool}(f(x))$. This follows immediately from the definition of monotonic increasing.

In particular, $\text{ReLU}$ is a monotonic increasing function. (Most NN activation functions in common usage are monotonic increasing. The important exceptions are Mish and similar functions which have recently become popular.)

It's cheaper to apply an activation to a smaller number of units, so $f(\text{maxpool}(x))$ can provide a slight reduction in computational cost. ReLUs are incredibly cheap, so the performance difference is not significant, but it might be more pronounced for a more expensive activation like $f=\tanh$.